# how to open a specific window on notification click in titanium android

Tags: android

i am developing a mobile app for android OS using titanium sdk version 3.1.1.GA and i am struggling to get it worked.
what i want to do is open a specific window when i click on the notification.
i am able to show a notification but when i click on it it shows the last window from the activity stack.

my code to create notification from service.js

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    // className : '<application id>.NotifierActivity',
    url : 'alertmsg.js',
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
});
intent.addCategory(Titanium.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

// Create a PendingIntent to tie together the Activity and Intent
var pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
    intent: intent,
    flags: Titanium.Android.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
});

// Create the notification
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    // icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
    //icon: Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.my_icon,
    contentTitle: 'Reminder pending',
    contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
    contentIntent: pending,
    //sound: 'click.mp3',
    defaults: Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.DEFAULT_ALL,
});
// Send the notification.
Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

code from my TiApp.xml file

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <services>
        <service type="interval" url="logservice.js"/>
    </services>
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" ></uses-permission>
    </manifest>
    <application>
        <activities>
            <activity url="alertmsg.js">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </activities>
    </application>
</android>
```

any help??
Thanks in advance.